# Getting "one or more error occured" error while upload file using iis to azure media services

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis

I am uploading videos from asp.net web application to azure media services using visual studio 2013.
While I am uploading videos from local machine it works fine but when I configure my application to iis it gives me an "One or more error occured" error.

Comment: You may be able to find more details in Windows Event Viewer. Please check there to see more details of error

Comment: What is the path you're using to read the local files in your web app?

Comment: Thanks qamar and JuanK for your reply, After uploading  the code on Azure server it is working fine. It was not working with local IIS because azure services does not connect with local system IIS. So we need to host the web app on azure server virtual machine's local IIS and it worked fine.